# How to access an array outside onreadystatechange (scope issue)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, scope, xmlhttprequest

I have a function ajaxCall() that calls a json document with an array inside.
The data that I get back from the xmlhttp.responseText are stored in the array, arrayImages. I need to have access to the array, arrayImages outside of the function ajaxCall(), because I need the length of that array, arrayImages.length.

```
function ajaxCall(){
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            arrayImages = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            output(arrayImages);

        } 
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I need something like this out of the function

```
var arrayLength = arrayImages.length;
```

Comment: It's not a *scope* issue, it's a *timing* issue. Your XHR is asynchronous, and the state change callback will be invoked only when the HTTP request makes progress.

Answer (score 1):

Since `onreadystatechange` is an asynchronous function, you can't know for sure when it will have your array returned. Hence, the only way to handle it is to use a callback function to output the `length` of the array when it is complete.
Like this:

```
function ajaxCall(){
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            arrayImages = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            output(arrayImages);

        } 
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function output(array)
{
   //your other stuff here
   var arrayLength = array.length;
}
```